# Which is the error inside the quotes Python 2.7

Tags: python, quotes, os.system

I am trying to configure Ansible in an automatic way with the following def:

```
   def configure_ansible():
    with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as f:
         valid_ips=[line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
    if os.path.isfile('/etc/ansible/hosts'): 
         open('/etc/ansible/hosts', 'w').close()
    os.system('cp /etc/hosts /etc/ansible/hosts')
    for valid_ip in valid_ips:
         os.system("sudo sed -i '14 s/^#//g' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg")
         os.system("sudo sed -i '22 s/^#//g' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg")
         if valid_ip == "localhost":
            os.system("su - ansible -c 'echo -e '\n\n\n' | ssh-keygen -t rsa'")
            os.system("su - ansible -c 'ssh-copy-id ansible@"+valid_ip)
```

Looks like the problem is inside the quotes of the last "if". Any idea how I can solve it?

#### UPDATE

I have followed chepner's recommendation, but the last line is not working properly. If I am using the code as below, the ssh-copy-id is not performed correctly and the ssh keys are not exchanged. I would need to introduce also the password to fully automate this process. Any idea how I can accomplish this? 
Here is what I have tried:

```
def create_user():
    users=["dante", "ansible"]
    with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as f:
         valid_ips=[line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
    for valid_ip in valid_ips:
        for user in users:
           subprocess.call(["sudo", "useradd", user])
           passwd_users = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "passwd", user], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
           passwd_users.communicate(input = "test123\ntest123")
           sudoers = open("/etc/sudoers", 'a')
           sudoers.write(user + "  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL \n")
           sudoers.close()

def configure_ansible():
    with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as f:
         valid_ips=[line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
    if os.path.isfile('/etc/ansible/hosts'):
         open('/etc/ansible/hosts', 'w').close()
    os.system('cp /etc/hosts /etc/ansible/hosts')
    config = "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"
    for valid_ip in valid_ips:
        subprocess.call(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "14 s/^#//g", config])
        subprocess.call(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "22 s/^#//g", config])
        if valid_ip == "localhost":
           keygen = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-u", "ansible", "ssh-keygen", "-t", "rsa"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
           keygen.communicate(input = "\n\n\n")
           copy_keygen = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-u", "ansible", "ssh-copy-id", "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no", valid_ip], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
           copy_keygen.stdin.write('test123\n')
```

Comment: In your second to last line, why do you have an extra ' at the end of the line?

Comment: In your last line, why *don’t* you have an extra ‘ added at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing single quote in that call to `os.system`:

```
os.system("su - ansible -c 'ssh-copy-id ansible@"+valid_ip+"'")
```

However, shell doesn't allow you to nest single quotes; the previous call should look something like:

```
os.system("su - ansible -c 'echo -e \"\n\n\n\" | ssh-keygen -t rsa'")
```

Even better, prefer `subprocess.call` to `os.system` in all cases:

```
config = "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"
for valid_ip in valid_ips:
     subprocess.call(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "14 s/^#//g", config])
     subprocess.call(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "22 s/^#//g", config])
     if valid_ip == "localhost":
        p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-u", "ansible", "ssh-keygen", "-t", "rsa"])
        p.communicate("\n\n\n")
        subprocesss.call(["sudo", "-u", "ansible", "ssh-copy-id", "ansible@" + valid_ip])
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. It's quite close to what I would like achieve. Still missing the password part to have a fully automated Ansible configuration with Python. I have updated the question with the code. Any ideas how I can fix the last part?

Comment: Configure `sudo` so that you can run these commands without a password.

Comment: I have the "create_user" def which does this, but the problem is still in the last two lines which contains the copy_keygen variable because the keys are not exchanged after those lines. The whole script until there is working fine.